# Credit risk book reference

Tags: references, risk, credit-scoring

Credit risk is a beautiful field that relies on basic notions of statistics and stochastic processes.

I have been studying it, and now I am trying to understand the market models such as KMV, Creditmetrics, credit risk +, credit portfolio view. All of these models use many statistical concepts and I have tried to read some books and they seem to be very imprecise.

There is also now a R library to run the creditmetrics (see [here](http://file:///tmp/mozilla_daniel0/CreditMetrics.pdf)), but I was not able to find the details of the model.

Can you suggest me a book that can present the details of each of the models without relying only on simplified examples, but on the clear steps to the implementation/evaluation of these models?